# Why Laravel passport login suddenly not working?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-passport

I am getting error for when try to login. I am not update any package at all but suddenly getting this error.

There was an error while creating the signature: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

But i am sure that the key file is in the correct format:

storage/oauth-private.key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
KEY VALUE
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

storage/oauth-public.key
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
KEY VALUE
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Any idea ? I am using Laravel 5.7, Passport 7.5.1, PHP 7.2.24.

Fix the error

```
There was an error while creating the signature: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
```

on vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/OpenSSL.php:27